# Tab Delimited Text File

Tags: c#, datagridview, text-files

I am able read a data contained in a text-file. This data is then coded to be displayed in a datagridview. The original format of the data is comma-delimited. Now I want to use the datagridview's data to save it using tab-delimited instead.

The problem is that, not all the fields are equal length so is giving me something like,

```
A B C
1 567889 123
```

and it should be like,

```
A B      C
1 567889 123
```

second example of what I want,

```
ABCDE ABC     A
123   1258741 528712
```

So no matter the header length column or data length column.

I used the string builder as, `sb.Append("{0}\t,{1}\t",field1, field2)` but it doesn't works. Also tried `write.Write(field + "\t")`

Comment: So you don't want Tab delimeted on the headers just the data? and are all the column data the ame length, eg: is column "B" aways 6 numbers or can it be more/less, if so what do you want to align your headers to, the longest column or just the first rows column data?

Comment: Can you be clearer about "it doesn't work" what is the result? What are you using to write on the file? Should it be enough to add two tabs instead of one?

Comment: The result is the first example. The problem is the header does not align with the data properly. I want to align it making the header match with the data, no matter if the header text is longer that the data column or viceversa.

Comment: I edited... read above please...

Comment: What are you using to visualise the results? If a CMD window, then each `TAB` character places the text afterwards at the the start of the next boundary of 8-character columns. If you redirect the output to a .txt file, open the text file, copy the contents, and then paste into Excel, does it work?

Comment: I am using notepad to visualize the output.

Comment: If you use Notepad to view variable length data in columns separated by tabs, the same problem as CMD: it will not align. Paste into Excel.

Comment: Try adding multiple tabs after each field... maybe two or three. What are you using to write to the file?

Comment: I am using StreamWriter. I will try that (adding more than \t) again. I tried that but get the thing worse but I will make another try though.

Comment: Uhm all this makes no sense to me :S

Comment: Are you perhaps using an extension like this? public static String ToString(this StringBuilder builder) { return builder.ToString().Replace("\t", " "); }

Comment: The column headings *may not* line up with the data in a tab-delimited file - it all depends on the length of the data/heading and the next available tab stop.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is not the right tool to use if you wish to visualise vertically aligned variable length data items separated by the `TAB` character.

Use an editor that supports elastic tab stops, such as: http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/ (scroll down to Java applet demo so you can try pasting text with single tab stops there).

Or paste the text into a tool designed to work with columns, such as Excel. It automatically recognises the tab as a column delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.PadRight` to format text in this way.

You just want to Pad using ' ' with the length of the header and add your tab.

Example:

```
string line = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", field1.PadRight(header1.Length, ' ')
                                           , field2.PadRight(header2.Length, ' ')
                                           , field3.PadRight(header3.Length, ' ')));
```

Result:

```
ABCDE   A       ABC
5       356475  5657
566     66      4
```